# Is FUF still available with NLTK?

Tags: nltk

There are almost no questions related to natural language generation on here, so I'm hoping somebody can answer my question. I'm doing work in NLG and have been reading through the official NLTK FUF manual [here](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2010s/clt310gen/docs/ImplementingFUFinNLTK.pdf).  I'm trying to do some sentence realization and tried importing the fuf module:

```
>>> from nltk import fuf
```

When I do that I get an error which says the module doesn't exist. I checked my NLTK folder and there is no fuf stuff there. I was under the impression that the module came standard with NLTK, but apparently not. I have version 2.0.4 installed on my Mac. FUF isn't a third party package I have to download is it? Please advise.

Thanks,

Mika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the FUF package is in the standard NLTK. [A note from 2009 in the NLTK google code repo](https://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/fuf/README?r=8565) reads:

> Moved NLTK-Contrib outside NLTK. Synced some changes for book.